# Procedural Node for Wood Texture For 3D Print

Tags: geometry, procedural

I am trying to 3d print an object which needs a wood texture. I have used shader nodes to create wood texture (is that even the right term? bc i have not used texture node..).

I want to try to use a voronoi or noise texture as i do in Shader Editor but apply the generated wood texture just to the surface. Is that something like a surface displacement? I dont want to use pics bc i need to be able to manipulate it procedurally.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uk4WsD4F9D8 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ECeHoATa74

Comment: Once you're happy with the procedural result, you need to bake it to a UV-mapped  image to use it in a _Displace_ modifier. which will deform the geometry itself, at modelling-time.